# Bootable hardware diagnostics software

Tags: hardware, diagnostics

I'm looking for a software which is bootable from a pendrive and capable to run various hardware tests. For example on a Fujitsu Primergy server.

My machine has stability problem and I'd like to narrow the cause of the fault by testing individual hardware components like CPU1, CPU2, RAM stick 1, RAM stick 2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For such hardware testing I'd recommend the free tools collection **Ultimate Boot CD**.

http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

It contains plenty of testing tools for CPU, RAM, hard drives, data recovery and more.

Despite the project's name, it can also be booted and used from an **USB memory stick**:

http://wiki.ultimatebootcd.com/index.php?title=Tutorials:USB_Installation

Comment: I agree that UBCD has plenty of stuff... My dream would be a software that boots from pendrive, does its tests and spits out that core3 in your 2. CPU is faulty,

Comment: btw I was able to diagnose the problem by removing all other CPU-s and disabling cores and testing each CPU one by one, but it's far from ideal :)